# How do I convert a number column like 200012 to a SAS date variable using PROC SQL?

Tags: date, sas, proc-sql

I have a SAS data set with a text field `customer_id` and a numeric field `month` in the format `YYYYMM`. I'm creating a view of these data, and I want to convert the data to a standard SAS date that will (hopefully) be preserved on export. For example:

```
proc sql;
    create view my_view as
        select customer_id, month from raw_dataset;
    quit;

proc export data = my_view
    file = "out.dta"
    dbms = stata replace;
quit;
```

Looking at the [date documentation](http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm), it looks like the number is in the form (although not the data type) `YYMMN.`, but I want it in a format that SAS can work with as a date, not just a number e.g. with `proc expand`.

I've seen a lot of questions using combinations of `put` and `datepart`, but since I don't want the variable as a string and don't already have a datetime variable, I'm not sure how to apply those.

How do I convert this column to a SAS date data type when I run this SQL query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`YYMMN.` is the right informat to use, and `input` is exactly how you get it there so it's a date. Try it!

```
data want;
  x='201403';
  y=input(x,YYMMN6.);
  put _all_;
run;
```

Of course, `y` now probably should be formatted nicely if you want to look at it, but it doesn't need to be.

In `PROC SQL` this works just the same way.

```
proc sql;
  create view want_v as
    select x, y, input(x,yymmn6.) as z format=date9.
        from want;
quit;
```

This also adds a format so it looks readable, but it's still a date variable underneath identical to `y`.

Comment: This gives me an error saying "INPUT function requires a character argument." I assume I'm getting this because my `month` variable is actually a six-digit number, not a string? I tried `input(put(month), yymmn6.)` as well, but I get the same error. I'm running it with `input(put(month, yymmn6.), yymmn6.)` now to see if that works, but the job takes a while because the data set is quite large.

Comment: If your field is a numeric field, then you have to `put` it to character first.  `input(put(datefield,6.),yymmn6.)`  You need the format to `put` it with in the `put` function.  Your second one doesn't work because that's acting as if your data were already an underlying date field - so `201403` would be something like 400 years in the future!

Comment: Ah, ok. That works. If I specify the input format as `MMDDYY10.`, will that automatically set the day as the first day of the month (which I want), or do I need to do more to expand it to a higher frequency? (I realize that's a somewhat separate question, but I realized I need to do that so I wanted to wrap up that one detail).

Comment: The day will always be the first day of the month when using `YYMMNw.` informat.  You can specify any format for the resulting field you wish.

Comment: Any benefit to this approach: `MDY(MOD(x,100),1,INT(x/100))`?